# ERROR: invalid byte sequence for encoding WITH psql

Tags: postgresql, psql

I've seen numerous issues in other posts with the copy command and:

```
ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xfc
```

And the consensus in these posts appears to be to specify the encoding in the command you're doing the copy with. I have done so:

```
psql -h localhost -p 5432 -d BOBDB -U BOB -c "\COPY \"BOBTB01\" FROM 'C:\Temp\file.csv' with csv HEADER ENCODING 'WIN1252'";
Password for user BOB:
**ERROR:  character with byte sequence 0x81 in encoding "WIN1252" has no equivalent in encoding "UTF8"
CONTEXT:  COPY BOBTB01, line 76589**
```

So, that confused me and I changed to UTF8 to WIN1252 and having done so I get a slightly different error, the failure is on a different line and the text is slightly different.

```
psql -h localhost -p 5432 -d BOBDB -U BOB -c "\COPY \"BOBTB01\" FROM 'C:\Temp\file.csv' with csv HEADER ENCODING 'UTF8'";
Password for user BOB:
**ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xfc
CONTEXT:  COPY BOBTB01, line 163**
```

This is the encoding shown in the database:

```
show client_encoding;
 client_encoding
-----------------
 UTF8
(1 row)
```

The file is from a reliable source and I happen to have "R" installed which also does .csv import. The file was pulled into "R" without issue, that's making me think it's not the file but something else. Is there another switch or syntax that can bypass these issues perhaps?

I'm not sure what is wrong.

Can you help?

Thanks.

Comment: Wel, obviously  the file is neither cp1252 nor UTF8. (and R probably just ignores the encoding, and treats the input stream as raw bytes)

Comment: Could be CP437 or cp852 or some other (the older dos/windows code pages). Or the file is just crippled and contains more than one encoding.